# I'm getting an error that the choice isn't defined in calculator function

Tags: python, variables, calculator

Problem on *line 24* or *line 10* of the `calculate()` function. It says that choice is not defined.

I've tried changing the defining variables and the integer variable that relate to each operator.

```
def start():
    print("Hey, I'm your calculator... \n")

    num1 = float(input("Enter your first number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter your second number: "))
    print("Operator list: \n 1. Addition + \n 2. Subtraction - \n 3. Multiply * \n 4. Division / \n")
    choice = int(input("Type the letter corresponding to your selection: "))

add = 1
subtract = 2
multiply = 3
divide = 4

def calculate():
    if choice == add or 1:
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif choice == subtract or 2:
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif choice == multiply or 3:
        print(num1 * num2)
    elif choice == divide or 4:
        print(num1 / num2)
    else:
        print("Oops! Please enter a valid operator: '+', '-', '*', or '/'")
        start()

start()
calculate()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:/Users/hkben/OneDrive/Desktop/PythonFiles/calculator.py", line 29, in 
>       calculate()
>     File "C:/Users/hkben/OneDrive/Desktop/PythonFiles/calculator.py", line 16, in calculate
>       if choice == add or 1:
>   NameError: name 'choice' is not defined

Comment: Initialize your `choice` variable outside functions.

Comment: Fixed. I don't know what I was thinking. I'm a student, still learning programming logic. Thank you.